# Applying threshold on correlation matrix in R

Tags: r

I am currently working on a dataset using R. I have created a correlation martix(Pearson)  for my variables.But now I want to put a threshold for the values shown in matrix. 
I am trying the following code:

```
cor_relation = cor(mydata_frame, use="all.obs", method="pearson")
```

I get the following output:

```
             200605_s_at      202592_at      202958_at
200605_s_at  1.000000000     0.295065389     0.169772244
202592_at    0.695065389     1.000000000     -0.534394180
202958_at    0.869772244     -0.534394180    1.000000000
```

I want to find the following output(when i put the threshold 0.6):

```
             200605_s_at      202592_at      202958_at
200605_s_at  1.000000000        NA              NA
202592_at    0.695065389     1.000000000        NA
202958_at    0.869772244        NA           1.000000000
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternate:

```
cor_relation[abs(cor_relation) < 0.6] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked perfectly.but i had to remove "abs" ,otherwise it was showing negative values as well,when i only need positive ones.

Answer (score 5):

```
is.na(cor_relation) <- abs(cor_relation) < 0.6
```

will replace all coefficients with an absolute value of less than 0.6 with `NA`.

Comment: how does this work internally? i thought R could not modify things by reference...

Comment: @Alex The object is not modified in place but copied two times. Try `tracemem(cor_relation)` and run the command above.